# Help figuring out the interface on this bill validator?

Tags: arduino, usb, rs232, rs485, rs422

I would like to interface [this bill validator](https://www.cranepi.com/en/products/solutions/note/validators/sc-advancetm#/) to a microcontroller (Arduino Mega). The website says it supports RS232,RS485,Optoisolated RS232 and USB interface.

The one I have is currently intefaced with a parking meter controller, with four wires. I figured two of these are power (+24V and GND). The other two wires are at between -5.0-5.3V and -8.1-8.3V. Any ideas which interfaces this could be?

Thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question to link to the actual datasheet for the device and the part number or model variant you have. Otherwise we're all guessing. Have you run a bill through it to see what the output does? Do you have an oscilloscope?

Answer (score 1):

The physical layer sounds like RS232 the asymetry +/-5V vs +/-8V  can be explained by the different ends having different drivers, possibly max232 one end and max3232 the other end.

While getting the physical interface connected to arduino is fairly simple for RS232 I was unable to locate ant protocol document and The only supported development envirionments are .net and Java.

https://www.cranepi.com/en/support#/downloads
select "banknote" "validators" "sc advance" "api" in the dropdowns.
(login required to proceed)

Maybe these can be reverse engineered to reveal the line protocol, but there's a good chance that the line protocol is encrypted.

It would probably be possible to interface with an ARM based system like Raspberry-Pi (over USB or RS232)  with either the java API or even the .net one either using mono, or by running "Windows 10 for IOT" on the Raspberry Pi

Comment: That may be true about the USB interface (and supporting drivers), however using RS232 or 485 it will be able to interface with anything that can communicate over serial.

Comment: @HarryBeadle, sure, but most bill handling hardware uses encrypted communications.

Comment: @Jasen I hadn't thought about that. Is it possible for you to link directly to the files you are referencing? That link just leads to a generic download page for the manufacturer.

Comment: sorry no, the API documentation is behind a login. I haven't tried to create an account there.

Answer (score 0):

From your measurements it sounds like this could be **RS232** *or* **RS485**.

The main difference between RS232 and RS485 is that RS485 uses a method called [differential signalling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_signaling), in which the logical level is defined by the difference between two signals. RS232 just uses a signal relative to ground.

Traditional RS232 varies between a maximum of -25V to 25V. A logical 0 is represented by a voltage above +3V and a logical 1 is represented by a voltage below -3V. You can read about the voltage levels you expect from RS232 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232#Voltage_levels).

There are two ways of finding out which protocol is being used:

- The fact that only two data lines are being used means that it is either [full duplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplex_(telecommunications)) RS232 or [simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_communication) RS485. If you can work out, or otherwise know, whether the device can both send and receive data, you know it operates on RS232.
- Use an oscilloscope to see how the data lines vary at the same time. If they are inverted versions of each other then it is RS485. If they behave independently of each other then it is likely RS232.

Comment: No, you have the RS232 voltage levels backwards. A mark (logical 1) is a negative voltage and a space (logical 0) is a positive voltage.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Fixed